# How to use GetDate() instead of Time() in this php function?

Tags: php, sql-server

How I can edit this PHP function below, so it will use `GetDate()` and will check like:

```
(nTime < DATEADD(DAY,-7,GETDATE()) OR nTime IS NULL)
```

instead of

```
if ((intval ($row['nTime']) + 604800) <= time() || !$count)
```

Basically I want to do the same but to use `GetDate()` instead of `time()`

Code:

```
$count = $db->doQuery('SELECT * FROM PANEL_NT WHERE strAccountID = ?', $_SESSION['strAccountID']);
$row = $db->doRead();

if ((intval ($row['nTime']) + 604800) <= time() || !$count)
{
    $db->doQuery('SELECT * FROM ACCOUNT_CHAR WHERE strAccountID = ?', $_SESSION['strAccountID']);
    $row = $db->doRead();
    $db->doQuery('EXEC NT ?', $_SESSION['strAccountID']);
    $db->doQuery('DELETE FROM PANEL_NT WHERE strAccountID = ?', $_SESSION['strAccountID']);
    $db->doQuery('INSERT INTO PANEL_NT VALUES (?, ?)', $_SESSION['strAccountID'], time());
    $this->content = Template::Load('error', array('errmsg' => Template::GetLangVar('NATION_TRANSFER_SUCCESS')));
}
else
{
    $this->content = Template::Load('error', 
        array('errmsg' => Template::GetLangVar('NATION_TRANSFER_ERROR'))
        );
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Where_%28SQL%29

Comment: Is there any way you can help me out and show me how I can do it actually ? I will be really grateful.

Comment: Actually time() doesn't work on Windows ?